# INSERT SELECT recursively

Tags: mysql

I have executed many times a similar query to this one

```
INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,...) SELECT col1, col2,... FROM table
```

at first, I just want to duplicate the rows in this table, then I ended up having more than 2000 rows on the table after just a few iterations, I know that I made a mistake because I forgot `LIMIT N`, but what I want know is: **If I keep repeating that query, what would happen to the MySQL server?**

I know this is similar to the [Wheat and chessboard problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_and_chessboard_problem).

Comment: Yes, the table will double its size in each iteration. If you keep repeating it, you will eventually use all the available disk space (or memory if the table uses the `memory` engine). Whether that will be in the 20th or 40th or Nth iteration depends on the row size and the total size of your disks/memory.

Comment: So `INSERT INTO` statement has no limit, and can handle millions of entries?

Comment: Yes, no limitations. Millions, billions, trillions, as much as your hardware can handle.

Comment: If you have a primary key or unique key on any columns in inserting the table, then the insert will stop due to duplicate key violation.